# Django model datetimefield updates but not in db

Tags: django, sqlite, datetime

I have the following in my Memo model

```
times_visited = models.IntegerField(default=0)
date_last_visited = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

When calling as below, only times_visited int is being updated in the database correctly, the date_visited stays the same as during initialisation. 
The print debug shows the correct time is stored in the model, but it seems it doesnt get pushed to the db. I did not override the save method.

```
memo.times_visited = memo.times_visited + 1
memo.last_visited = timezone.now()
memo.save()

print("Last visited: " + str(memo.last_visited))
```

Should this not be working this way?

Comment: try without brackets `default=timezone.now` or best is `auto_now=True`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now

Comment: Thanks @BearBrown removing the brackets did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
memo.date_last_visited = timezone.now()
```

not

```
memo.last_visited = timezone.now()
```

As dirkgroten said you are assigning `last_visited` property to memo object

Comment: no it wouldn't throw an error. You can always assign any new property you want to a python object.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Interestingly also removing the () after timezone.now in the initialisation solved the issue.